# Clear with query in MS Access 97 database using C# with date

Tags: c#, ms-access

I created a button with link code to the MS Access 97 database and a delete query, but when I run the code, nothing is deleted from the database. The search must be done on the first column which is `id_car` which is composed of XXYYYYZZZZ (XX = Month, YYYY = Year, ZZZZ = is a code that doesn't interest me)

```
string MesePartenza = Mese1;
string MeseFinale = Mese2;

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("DELETE * FROM cartellini WHERE id_car BETWEEN '" + MesePartenza + "" + AnnoP.ToString() + "*' AND '" + MeseFinale + "" + AnnoF.ToString() + "*'", connect);

OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you even instantiating an `OleDbDataAdapter` if you're not ever using it at all ?? Just leave that out - not needed, not helpful at all. Just create the `OleDbCommand` and then call `.ExecuteNonQuery()` on that - just as you're doing - that's plenty enough!

Comment: I thank you for the answer, I still deleted what you recommended but it doesn't delete anything

Answer (score 0):

Print your finished sql and post it here. Also, you can't use wildcards here. Try:

```cs
String sql = "DELETE * FROM cartellini WHERE id_car BETWEEN '" + MesePartenza + AnnoP.ToString() + "0000' AND '" + MeseFinale + AnnoF.ToString() + "ZZZZ'";
Console.WriteLine(sql);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, connect);
```